# How can I query in laravel from a column in the db that has single values and arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am doing a complex query that looks at data in the database from a column that has single and multiple values depending on whats added. Here is a snippet of what might be sent out:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"offer_title": "",
"offer headline": "",
"offer_subheader": "small subheader",
"image": "2015-08-10-09-2.png",
"thumbnail": "2015-08-10-09-1.png",
"offer_terms": "the terms",
"venue_name": "the venue number 2",
"venue_headline": "the headline",
"venue_description": "the venue is awesome",
"venue_phone_number": "00445676833",
"venue_website": "site.co.uk",
"venue_latitude": 999999.99,
"venue_longitude": -999999.99,
"offer_when": "tomorrow",
"days": "tuesday",
"featured_date": "",
"offer_end_time": "08:50",
"offer_start_time": "08:50",
"created_at": "2015-08-10 09:50:50",
"updated_at": "2015-08-11 07:50:59",
"deleted_at": null,
"offer_headline": "large header",
"venue_address": "55 road",
"offer_start_date": "08/11/2015",
"offer_end_date": "08/11/2015"
},
{
"id": 2,
"offer_title": "",
"offer headline": "",
"offer_subheader": "the subheader",
"image": "2015-08-11-09-logotype.png",
"thumbnail": "2015-08-11-09-logotype.png",
"offer_terms": "terms",
"venue_name": "a name",
"venue_headline": "this headline",
"venue_description": "the venue is cool",
"venue_phone_number": "00445676833",
"venue_website": "anothersite.co.uk",
"venue_latitude": 999999.99,
"venue_longitude": -999999.99,
"offer_when": "tomorrow",
"days": "monday,tuesday,wednesday",
"featured_date": "",
"offer_end_time": "20:29",
"offer_start_time": "15:29",
"created_at": "2015-08-11 09:31:12",
"updated_at": "2015-08-11 09:31:12",
"deleted_at": null,
"offer_headline": "the header",
"venue_address": "55 road",
"offer_start_date": "08/11/2015",
"offer_end_date": "08/11/2015"
}
]
```

As you can see in each object there is a column called `days` each one has either a list or a single value. What I am trying to achieve is by getting the current day today query the db and show up items in here that match the current day today so for example, its tuesday so all offers with either 'tuesday' or 'tuesday,wednesday,friday' should show up as it's tuesday today, if they don't they would show up another day. Here is what I have tried so far which only ever gives me the single valued `days` as the result not the one with the array in it:

```
public function getOffers(Offer $offer)
{

    $mytime = Carbon::now();
    $today = $mytime->format('m/d/Y');
    $day = $mytime->format('l');
    $thisDay = strtolower($day);
    $offerWhen = $offer['offer_when'];

     foreach(Offer::all() as $offerObject){
        $offerObject->update(['offer_when' => 'tomorrow']);
        $the_days = $offerObject['days'];
        $offersAll = $offerObject::whereIn('days', array($the_days) )->orWhere('days', '=', array($the_days))->get();
        return $offersAll;
     }

}
```

The above query only returns one object with just 'tuesday' in it and not the one with an array that still has 'tuesday' in it.

The ideal scenario would be that it only ever shows results with the current day in the 'days' column. The current day is created with `Carbon::now()->format('l');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand everything in your code, but best approach here is to try with LIKE condition.

Try something like that:

```
->where('days', 'LIKE', '%' . $dayName . '%')
```

This will work here well because all day names are pretty different and none of them contains the other (like with `big`, `bigger` which would cause problems here).